# @import directory statement in less

Tags: express, gruntjs, less, webstorm

My less organization right now is as follows:

```
styles/pages/page1/index.less
styles/pages/page1/tab1.less
...
styles/widgets/widget1.less
styles/widgets/widget2.less
...
styles/tools/partials.less
...
styles/app.less
```

The entirety of my app.less file are `@import` statements to bring all the other parts in.

```
@import "tools/partials";
@import "widgets/widget1";
@import "widgets/widget2";
@import "pages/page1/index";
@import "pages/page1/tab1";
//...
```

These statements are maintained manually, which sucks. Is there a better way?

I'm dreaming of something like this:

```
@import "tools/partials";
@import "widgets/*";
@import "pages/**/*";
```

Maybe some kind of script to handle this on the editor level (using WebStorm)? Or perhaps some kind of plugin for the less compiler itself?

Right now I'm serving less files from an express middleware in my app, but I can easily switch to grunt if there's a solution there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at [`grunt-less-imports`](https://github.com/MarcDiethelm/grunt-less-imports). It maintains an imports file based on your files (`app.less` in your case).

Here is how I use it in my recent project. I have a bunch of less files, like so:

[image: Less files]

And I use `grunt-less-imports` like so (gruntfile.js):

```
less_imports: {
        options: {
            banner: '// Compiled stylesheet'
        },
        styles: {
            src: ['<%= config.app %>/assets/less/**/*.less', '!<%= config.app %>/assets/less/styles.less'],
            dest: '<%= config.app %>/assets/less/styles.less'
        }
    },
```

This task make a `styles.less` with imports:

[image: Resulting imports file]

So you just add-delete your less files, and task do the job importing them. Is it what you looking for?

### Update

If you need more structure in your imports file, you can get some. For example, i have two folders with less files, `page-frame-blocks` and `popups` and want them to be imported first:

```
less_imports: {
        options: {
            banner: '// Compiled stylesheet'
        },
        styles: {
            src: [
                '<%= config.app %>/assets/less/page-frame-blocks/*.less',
                '<%= config.app %>/assets/less/popups/*.less',
                '<%= config.app %>/assets/less/*.less',
                '!<%= config.app %>/assets/less/styles.less'],
            dest: '<%= config.app %>/assets/less/styles.less'
        }
    },
```

Now my imports file looks like this:

[image: Order of imports]

Want `popups` styles be imported first? Just move it to top in `src` section. You get the idea - you can explicitly say what folders you want and in what order using grunt globbing patterns.

Comment: I knew I could do something like that. Problem is, how do you maintain the import order? Eg. Tools.less must be imported before page1.less?

Comment: Author of `grunt-less-imports` here. Thanks for the mention. If there's something missing, please let me know in the issues on Github.

Comment: @MarcDiethelm my dest file is empty after a successful run (Done, without errors). This is in my files section: 'core/less/theme.less': ['core/less/theme/**/*.less'] and of course there are .less files in the folder . Can you think of something?

Comment: @YoniLevy Hi, can you open an issue on Github for this please? Helping you here in the comment section is not practical. However what I can see already is that your globbing pattern includes the output recursively.

https://github.com/MarcDiethelm/grunt-less-imports/issues

Comment: good advice, but the building didnt work for me correctly unless i used the advice here https://github.com/MarcDiethelm/grunt-less-imports/issues/15#issuecomment-277115209